# Why is jQTouch not working out of the box for my HTML?

Tags: html, jqtouch

I'm new to [jQTouch](http://jqtouch.com/) -- it's pretty awesome -- but I'm finding that I'm not able to get it to work out of the box for my HTML, even though I'm following the [getting started](https://github.com/senchalabs/jQTouch/wiki/gettingstarted) guide as well as the [markup guidelines](https://github.com/senchalabs/jQTouch/wiki/Markup,-Theming-and-Styling).

Specifically, each of my screens is a `<section>` element (direct child of `<body>`) with a unique ID, and I have links to those IDs, e.g. `<a href="#screen-a">`. This seems to follow the convention of the demo code, but yet the demo code works and my code doesn't.

Here is the HTML structure of my `<body>`:

```
<section id="main-menu">
    <header class="toolbar"><!-- ... --></header>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li class="arrow"><a href="#screen-a">Screen A</a></li>
            <li class="arrow"><a href="#screen-b">Screen B</a></li>
            <li class="arrow"><a href="#screen-c">Screen C</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <footer><!-- ... --></footer>
</section>

<section id="screen-a"><!-- ... --></section>
<section id="screen-b"><!-- ... --></section>
<section id="screen-c"><!-- ... --></section>

<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="jqtouch.min.js"></script>

<script src="init.js"></script>
```

And my `init.js` simply initializes jQTouch (no custom options):

```
var jQT = new $.jQTouch({});
```

When I load my page, the UI appears fine, and I can confirm jQTouch was initialized because my `jQT` variable exists.

But when I click any link, the location bar changes to the new hash (e.g. "#screen-a"), but the UI doesn't change. And the JavaScript console starts throwing repeated multiple **No pages in history** errors.

(When I use the unminified jQTouch.js, these errors come from inside the jQTouch `goBack()` function, which is being called from the `dumbLoopStart()` timer.)

Note that this happens for me both in desktop Safari and in Mobile Safari on the iPhone. But that's very strange, because their [demo](http://jqtouch.com/preview/demos/main/) works just fine for me on both.

I've banged my head against this for hours to no avail. Does anyone have ideas or suggestions or tips for what I might be doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Why does your code use section elements when the example uses divs?

Comment: In the spirit of HTML5, I thought section was a more semantic element than div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created an test from your provided example (with the addition of the style imports). Simply removing the <nav> elements resolved the issue for me.

Comment: Yes, you're right! It seems that the default selector for handling lists is a tad overaggressive, looking for "body > * > ul li a" instead of e.g. just "ul li a". Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I believe your main elements have to be div's. Additionally, you need a class of "current" on the div that should be displayed first.
I don't know if the version you are using requires this, but what I pulled via git a while back requires that all of your main elements be contained in a div with an id of "jqt".

```
<div id="jqt">
   <div id="main-menu" class="current">
       <ul>
           <li class="arrow"><a href="#screen-a">Screen A</a></li>
           <li class="arrow"><a href="#screen-b">Screen B</a></li>
           <li class="arrow"><a href="#screen-c">Screen C</a></li>
       </ul>
   </div>

   <div id="screen-a"><!-- ... --></div>
   <div id="screen-b"><!-- ... --></div>
   <div id="screen-c"><!-- ... --></div>
</div>

<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="jqtouch.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but I can confirm neither of these are the problem when I change the demo to also use section and remove the explicit class="current" -- it still works. (EDIT: meant to insert newlines, not submit.) The jqtouch.js also has no instance of the word "div", and it has an explicit check that if no screen has class="current", it adds it to the first screen.

Comment: And the container div (#jqt in your example) is no longer the pattern. The demo doesn't have one, and the markup guidelines say "jQTouch takes any direct descendent under the `<body>` and converts it into a full-screen panel".

Comment: You are correct, a quick scan through the JS file reveals no requirement of the "div" tag. 
I think the demo is based on version 1b2 which is quite old at this point. We ran into several problems with it and pulled the latest version from github (https://github.com/senchalabs/jQTouch/blob/master/jqtouch/jqtouch.js) and made changes as needed. You will find in the current version in github that the "jqt" id is the pattern. Could you post a more complete example that exhibits the behavior?

Comment: This answer veered so far away from the solution, I felt it better to just create a separate answer.

Comment: Thanks, great tip! I grabbed the latest version on Git and it indeed fixes this problem as well (it has fallback handling for any link now).